# create area in MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, area

In an MVC4 web application, what is the best way to create an Area? Can it be automated or is it a manual process of creating the controller, View folder etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the ASP.NET MVC project in the solution explorer and select `Add Area...` in the contextual menu. Then type the name of the area and proceed:

[image]