# how to reference different projects in one solution and access through link in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I have two projects in one solution one is company.admin and other is company.web, now I want to link these two for example if I write http://localhost60693.com/web then company.web view should be open and when I write http://localhost60693.com/admin then it will redirect me to admin panel...please help me..what logic I should implement in controller or action links? and also guide me how to publish multiple projects in MVC4? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @maxs87 say, you can create areas for every section. If you must use them in separate project, conside that you have multiple web application in one solution, so you have multiple sites after deploying. You can create helper link to cross from this site to other or come back:

```
public static string MyRedirectLink(string siteName, string controller, string action, string text)
    {  
       StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
       string url = "http://" + siteName + "/";
       url = url + controller + "/" + action;
       result.AppendFormat("<a href=\"{0}\" target=\"blank\" >{1}", url, text);
       result.AppendLine("</a>");
    }
```

And in view use it:

```
@Html.Raw(MyLibrary.HtmlCodeHelper.MyRedirectLink("mysite", "admin", "index", "Go to Admin site" ))
```

Comment: I must say that you guys should see NOPCOMMERCE solution they did the same as I have asked here

Answer (score 0):

I can recomend you do not put your controllers and view to different projects. Try to keep them in main project. Use different projects to keep the busines logic of your application like Models, DataTransferObjects, DBProviders, helpers etc.

If you want create 'web' and 'admin' sections in you application you can user Areas for this.
Right click on main project in your solution and click 'Area' or 'CreateArea'. For more information look here [create area in MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779745/create-area-in-mvc-project)

Comment: i know that, but in this scenario i have to make admin separate from web and in link i want to map links of admin..please guide me that way

Comment: answer plz, I have two different mvc4 projects in one solution, one is company.web and other is company.admin...

Answer (score 0):

In your development if you open a View by right clicking it and "View in browser", one project will start with:

```
http://localhost:<firstprojectport>/
```

and the other one will start with:

```
http://localhost:<secondprojectport>/
```

You can use them to reference until you are ready to deploy and then use their site url instead

I am using this myself in a solution where my company wants to integrate all the different old websites and administration tools into one administrative site with the same username/password and Single Sign On-functionality for all of them in a simple way and still separate the codes for all of the sites and tools

Comment: how do you maintain user information when you navigate across those different sites? Obviously you need to verify that a user had previously logged in successfully before navigation to another site. I am using session variables and was curious on your way of doing it.

Comment: You need to implement SSO(Single Sign On), which will ensure that the different projects in the same solution has the same log in source and trust.. I did this in a recent project myself very recently but don´t have the code with me at the moment.. here is a link to the site i used to learn it and it worked like a charm, as long as the projects(sites) are in the same solution: http://arunendapally.com/post/implementation-of-single-sign-on-(sso)-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: That's awesome thanks! If you have any other helpful references in this matter please provide. :)

Comment: No problem, the link i provided got it all working perfectly, didn´t need any other references, but if you run into problems, ask away! Though start a new question so we don+t clutter this thread since it already has it´s answer